# WooCommerce Cart Total Table chronology order change

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

How do i add 'Delivery Fee' after Sales Tex[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Woocommerce cart page, you need to override the template `cart/cart-totals.php` [**via the theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

So you will have to move the Fee block:

```
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

after the Tax block:

```
    <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) :
        $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
        $estimated_text  = WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping()
                ? sprintf( ' <small>' . __( '(estimated for %s)', 'woocommerce' ) . '</small>', WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] )
                : '';

        if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                    <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->label ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <tr class="tax-total">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) . $estimated_text; ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<!-- #### ====> IN HERE <==== #### -->
```

That will  do the trick…

---

For **checkout page** it will be similiar editing `checkout/review-order.php` template file.

You will have to move **the Fee block**:

```
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

after the **Tax block**:

```
    <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
        <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <tr class="tax-total">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<!-- #### ====> IN HERE <==== #### -->
```

It will work nicely. It's not possible to do it in another way.

---

Documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)